# Machine learning algorithm to classify matrices

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, supervised-learning

I want to know what could be first choice for a machine learning algorithm to classify matrices.

Each matrix belongs to either class A or class B.
The classification problem is: To classify each matrix into either class A or class B (say signal matrix or noise matrix).

Each matrix is arranged in a fashion where each row contains certain features of an object associated with the matrix.

I obviously have thousands of such class A and class B matrices to train on.

I will be really obliged if you could help. Thanks.

Comment: This is too brood, there are many answers, basically any kind of classifier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use a simple neural network for this task, flatten your matrix and feed the matrix entries as inputs to your network. However, I would suggest using a convolutional neural network, these have had very good performance on image data, which is essentially a matrix. This class of NN is powerful because it uses a neighborhood around each point as an input and thus significantly reduces the number of inputs to the network, which in turn reduces the model complexity.

I would also suggest using some matrix transformations to get better features. For example you can perform eigenvector decomposition of the matrix to ensure that the features you are feeding to your network are orthogonal. This may increase performance of your classifier.

If you give us some examples of your dataset we can help you build a network to start testing ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have indeed starting experimenting with CNNs using tensorflow.